# created persisted computed columns when the user defined scalar function appears to be non-deterministic

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have a scalar UDF that I know to be deterministic, however SQL doesn't.  Is there a way to declare it as deterministic so that I can then use it in a persisted computed column definition?

further clarification:
The purpose of this exercise is that I need to harvest out specific values from an XML column on the row.  I can't use the `value` method of the xml column in my computed column definition, but I can use it in a UDF.  I know the xpath query in the `value` method will produce the same output give the same input so while I certainly understand that not all calls to `value` will be deterministic I want to assert that mine is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out I needed to do was add `WITH SCHEMABINDING` to the UDF definition.  the `value` method is determinisitic after all. (Apparently because the XQuery doesn't include dates?)